# MVC Net 6 Get Object from SelectList using its id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hello i am triying to figure out how to get the object after is selected in the selectlist, the selectlist holds the "Id" field and "Code" field, but i want to get access to the other fields of the object after is selected. I would like to show the "Amount" field and the "Coin.Name" of the object in the view after the selecction.

**Order Model**

```
public class Order
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    [Display(Name = "Proveedor")]
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Proveedor")]
    public virtual Provider Provider { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    [Display(Name = "Pais")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pais")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; } = null!;

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    [Display(Name = "Categoria")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Categoria")]
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Coigo de Orden")]
    public string Code { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Moneda")]
    public int CoinId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Moneda")]
    public virtual Coin Coin { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Monto")]
    [Precision(18, 2)]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha Tope")]
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    [Display(Name = "Comprador")]
    public int BuyerId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comprador")]
    public virtual Buyer Buyer { get; set; } = null!;

    [StringLength(500)]
    [Display(Name = "Comentarios")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    [Display(Name = "Campo 1")]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    [Display(Name = "Campo 2")]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    [Display(Name = "Campo 3")]
    public string Field3 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    [Display(Name = "Campo 4")]
    public string Field4 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int AuditUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User AuditUser { get; set; } = null!;

    public DateTime AuditDateTime { get; set; }

    public bool AuditDelete { get; set; }
}
```

**Coin Model**

```
public class Coin
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public int AuditUserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User AuditUser { get; set; } = null!;

    [Required]
    public DateTime AuditDateTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool AuditDelete { get; set; }
}
```

**Create Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int idPayment)
    {
        ViewData["id"] = idPayment;
        ViewData["OrderId"] = new SelectList(_context.Orders.Include(o => o.Coin).Where(x => x.AuditDelete == false).OrderBy(x => x.Code), "Id", "Code");
        ViewData["PaymentStatusId"] = new SelectList(_context.PaymentsStatus.Where(x => x.AuditDelete == false).OrderBy(x => x.Status), "Id", "Status");

        return View();
    }
```

**Create View**

```
    @model WebApplicationDailyPayments.Models.Database.PaymentDetails

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Crear";
}

<h1>Crear</h1>

<h4>Detalle de pagos</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PaymentId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="PaymentId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PaymentId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="OrderId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="OrderId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.OrderId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PaymentStatusId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="PaymentStatusId" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.PaymentStatusId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AmountPaid" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AmountPaid" class="form-control" id="AmountPaid" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AmountPaid" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Rate" class="control-label"></label>
                <div class="form-check form-switch">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="rateChecked" checked="">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Multiplicar - Dividir</label>
                </div>
                <input asp-for="Rate" class="form-control" id="Rate"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Rate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AmountPaidFinal" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="AmountPaidFinal" class="form-control" id="AmountPaidFinal" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="AmountPaidFinal" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary" />&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Index" asp-route-idPayment="@ViewData["id"]">Regresar a la Lista</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
        $(function(){

            $("#AmountPaid,#Rate").keyup(function (e) {

            var q=$("#AmountPaid").val().toString().replace(",",".");
            var p = $("#Rate").val().toString().replace(",", ".");
            var c = document.getElementById('rateChecked');
            var result=0;

            if(q!=="" && p!=="" && $.isNumeric(q) && $.isNumeric(p))
            {
                if(c.checked)
                {
                    result = parseFloat(q) * parseFloat(p);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = parseFloat(q) / parseFloat(p);
                }
              
            }
                $("#AmountPaidFinal").val((Math.round(result * 100) / 100).toString().replace(".", ","));
          });

});
    </script>
}
```

**Edit 1**

I added in the controller to pass the Orders to the view

```
ViewData["Orders"] = _context.Orders.Include(o => o.Coin).Where(x => x.AuditDelete == false).ToList();
```

I added in the view to get the orders

```
@{
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<WebApplicationDailyPayments.Models.Database.Order>)(ViewData["Orders"]))
            {
                var a = item.Id;
            }

        }
```

Now i get the Orders in the view, now i need to filter by Id selecetd in the selectlsit

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor select changes to perform corresponding operations.

Below is my test code, you can refer to it.

In the view, I use JavaScript to monitor whether the select changes, so as to obtain the selected Id for matching:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="OrderId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select id="my_select" asp-for="OrderId" class="form-control" asp-items="@ViewBag.OrderId"></select>
</div>

<script>
    $("#my_select").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).children(":selected").attr("value");
        var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["Orders"]));
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i].id == parseInt(id))
            {
                console.log("Coin.Name:"+array[i].coin.name);
                console.log("Amount:" + array[i].amount);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Test Result:

[image]

Is this what you want?